# How to change layout or table from SQL data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to change SQL query but I don't know how.

Currently I join 3 tables to get one result. Actually my expectation the result will be like [this expectated output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAmNk.png). But the current SQL that I made the result be like [current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loHpK.png) with the query that I used like

```
SELECT 
    KioskLocation, RatingCode, 
    COUNT(RatingCode) AS RatingCount 
FROM 
    [Transaction] AS A 
INNER JOIN 
    [Kiosk] AS B ON A.TXKioskID = B.KioskID 
INNER JOIN 
    [Rating] AS C ON A.TXRatingID = C.RatingID 
WHERE 
    A.TXDate >= '2020-02-26' 
    AND A.TXDate < '2020-02-28' 
GROUP BY 
    RatingCode, KioskLocation 
ORDER BY 
    KioskLocation
```

How can I change this SQL query to get my expectated output?

Sorry my English is so bad.

Comment: please don't post image. Post your sample data & expected result as text please

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. You might find the answer if you search for `conditional aggregation`.

Comment: Sorry sir. This is my first time using stackoverflow. I hope you can help me guide using this stackoverflow. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can write query with conditional aggregation as given below in SQL Server.

```
SELECT 
    KioskLocation, CASE WHEN RatingCode = 'Bad' THEN COUNT(RatingCode) END AS Bad,
     CASE WHEN RatingCode = 'Good' THEN COUNT(RatingCode) END AS Good,
      CASE WHEN RatingCode = 'NotGood' THEN COUNT(RatingCode) END AS [NotGood],
     CASE WHEN RatingCode = 'VeryGood' THEN COUNT(RatingCode) END AS [VeryGood],
      CASE WHEN RatingCode = 'Excellent' THEN COUNT(RatingCode) END AS [Excellent]
FROM 
    [Transaction] AS A 
INNER JOIN 
    [Kiosk] AS B ON A.TXKioskID = B.KioskID 
INNER JOIN 
    [Rating] AS C ON A.TXRatingID = C.RatingID 
WHERE 
    A.TXDate >= '2020-02-26' 
    AND A.TXDate < '2020-02-28' 
GROUP BY 
    KioskLocation 
ORDER BY 
    KioskLocation
```